# why md-datepicker shows year ahead when opened?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, datetimepicker

Hi I have angular material datepicker:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="vm.endDate" md-min-date=vm.minDate></md-datepicker>
```

But when I open datepicker it opens on 2018 year (1year ahead)

[image]

how to make it open on todays date or date which is in vm.endDate ?

I've noticed that when I remove vm.minDate - it opens on 2017

Comment: We need to see the definition of vm.minDate. Most likely you initialized this incorrectly.

Comment: yes you are right. solved!!thanks